# App error while selecting a MDCheckbox in kivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a `MDList` with `MDCheckbox` and I need to select some of the items of the list but e.g. when I select the first item the last one gets selected too, and when I select the second item the penultimate item gets selected too and vice versa if I select the last element then the first on gets selected too. This only happens with the first and last two elements of the list, when I select an element in between those it works fine. How can I prevent this to happen?

Here's an similar example of my code:

```
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch, ThreeLineListItem, ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from functools import partial

KV='''
WindowManager:
    #LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    LeftCheckbox:


<MainWindow>
    name: 'main'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'test'

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            spacing: dp(10)
            padding: dp(20)

            RecycleView:
                id: rv
                key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
                key_size: 'height'
                bar_width: dp(10)
                RecycleBoxLayout:
                    padding: dp(10)
                    default_size: None, dp(80)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'



'''

product_dict={'name 1': (1, 2),
                'name 2': (3,4),
                'name 3':(4,2),
                'name 4':(4,2),
                'name 5':(4,2),
                'name 6':(4,2),
                'name 7':(4,2),
                'name 8':(4,2),
                'name 9':(4,2) ,
                'name 10':(4,2)}


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ListItemWithCheckbox(ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem):
    pass

class LeftCheckbox(ILeftBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette="Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):

        self.set_list()

    def set_list(self):

        self.root.get_screen('main').ids.rv.data = []
        for key in product_dict:
            self.root.get_screen('main').ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "ListItemWithCheckbox",
                    "text": key,
                    "secondary_text": f'Item 1: {product_dict[key][0]}',
                    "tertiary_text": f'Item 2: {product_dict[key][1]}',
                    "on_press": partial(self.action, key)
                }
            )

    def action(self, instance):
        print(instance)

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `RecycleView` recycles the `viewclass`, properties that get set in the `viewclass` will be reflected in recycled instances of the `viewclass` unless you explicitly handle those properties. So, if the `state` of the `LeftCheckbox` in your `ListItemWithCheckbox` gets set to `down` in one instance, it will remain as `down` when that instance is recycled to display another item from the `data`.

The fix is to handle the `state` of the `LeftCheckbox` in your `data`. In order to do that, you need to be able to determine which item of the `data` is currently associated with a `LeftCheckbox`.

One way to do that is to add properties to the `ListItemWithCheckbox`:

```
class ListItemWithCheckbox(ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem):
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)  # is this checkbox down
    data_index = NumericProperty(-1)  # index into the RV data

    def state_changed(self):
        self.selected = self.ids.lcb.state == 'down'  # set the selected property

        # save the change to the data
        rv = MDApp.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').ids.rv
        rv.data[self.data_index]['selected'] = self.selected
```

Then adjust the `set_list()` method to initialize the new properties:

```
def set_list(self):

    self.root.get_screen('main').ids.rv.data = []
    index = 0
    for key in product_dict:
        self.root.get_screen('main').ids.rv.data.append(
            {
                "viewclass": "ListItemWithCheckbox",
                "text": key,
                "secondary_text": f'Item 1: {product_dict[key][0]}',
                "tertiary_text": f'Item 2: {product_dict[key][1]}',
                "on_press": partial(self.action, key),
                "selected": False,
                "data_index": index
            }
        )
        index += 1
```

And in the `kv` modify the `ListItemWithCheckbox`:

```
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:
    LeftCheckbox:
        id: lcb
        on_press: root.state_changed()  # save change to the data
        state: 'down' if root.selected else 'normal' #  get state from the "selected" property
```